# How to send graph in image format to web page

Tags: java, spring, web-application-design

I have to show the image of any graph (say pie chart) on web UI. That image must contain pie chart. But i don't want to add any functionality in UI code. I want to fetch data from DB on server , based on that i want to get pie chart and that pie chart will be sent in image format at UI. Is it possible to do so? Hopefully i am able to explain my problem. I am using spring mvc at server side. I tried many links but not able to get appropriate solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFreeChart seems like a library that can create graphs for you in the form of image files:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/